# Class instantiated multiple times; how to tell which one is being called?

Tags: java

I am working on the following code, where the same class is instantiated twice with two different names:

```
private final CdsResEventRepository hcrsResEventRepo;
private final CdsResEventRepository pcrsResEventRepo;
...
if (queueRec.getDbId() == DbId.HCRS) {
  delCnt = hcrsResEventRepo.delete(seqId);
} else if (queueRec.getDbId() == DbId.PCRS) {
  delCnt = pcrsResEventRepo.delete(seqId);
}
```

Depending on the condition, the same method may be called with one class name or the other.

From inside CdsResEventRepository.delete, how can I tell whether it was called as hcrsResEventRepo.delete or pcrsResEventRepo.delete?

My first thought was to use getStackTrace() to get the called Class. However, this returns only "CdsResEventRepository", and does not tell whether it was the hcrsResEventRepo instantiation or the pcrsResEventRepo instantiation.

From within the method being called, what is the best way to tell which instantiation was used to call it?

Comment: Are hcrsResEventRepo and pcrsResEventRepo different subclass of CdsResEventRepository? Or are they the instance of CdsResEventRepository itself?

Comment: @AbhishekGarg hcrsResEventRepo and pcrsResEventRepo are both instances of CdsResEventRepository itself.

Comment: Logic in a class should not have to know about variables that they're running off. But each instance knows itself. `hcrsResEventRepo` and `pcrsResEventRepo` are instances of the same class, but how they were constructed or the state they're holding should be enough to tell the running code what to do when the distinction matters.

Comment: @ernest_k From within hcrsResEventRepo / pcrsResEventRepo, how can I tell how it was called?

Comment: @ernest_k I suppose I could add another parameter, for example delCnt = hcrsResEventRepo.delete("H", seqId), but I thought there might be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: @SagebrushGardener You'd have to use either another method parameter on delete() (and then have just one instance of CdsResEventRepository) or a new field in CdsResEventRepository, keep 2 but differently constructed instances of CdsResEventRepository

Comment: @ernest_k It seems odd that there is no convenient way to tell from within CdsResEventRepository.delete(), which instance was used to call it. It looks like adding another parameter is the way to go: hcrsResEventRepo.delete("H", seqId) or pcrsResEventRepo.delete("P", seqId). The original code was written by a senior developer, and I'm not sure what the point was of creating two different instances of the class. There does not seem to be any other purpose for it.

Answer (score 0):

What about a booleand flag? `boolean wasCalled`, if you can modify your class. If you can't, a boolean variable between lines. A quick solution, but works.

```
boolean hcrsResEventRepoDeleted = false;
if (queueRec.getDbId() == DbId.HCRS) {
  delCnt = hcrsResEventRepo.delete(seqId);
  hcrsResEventRepoDeleted = true;
} else if (queueRec.getDbId() == DbId.PCRS) {
  delCnt = pcrsResEventRepo.delete(seqId);
}
```

Then do something with the boolean. If you have access to you class:

```
delCntH = hcrsResEventRepo.delete(seqId, DbId.HCRS, queueRec.getDbId());
delCntP = hcrsResEventRepo.delete(seqId, DbId.PCRS, queueRec.getDbId());
```

and call `queueRec.delete(seqId)` inside that new `delete` method with the if logic and the extra info;

Comment: I am not seeing how this can tell me, from within the called class, which instance of the class is being called.

Comment: @SagebrushGardener then you have to do something with that boolean, check it's value and do what you need if it was called or not

Comment: It is within the called class that I need to know how it was called.

Comment: @SagebrushGardener do you have access to the code of that class? can you modify it?

Comment: Technically yes, but I am working with existing code written by a senior developer and I am trying to limit my changes. I suppose I could add another parameter, for example delCnt = hcrsResEventRepo.delete("H", seqId), but I thought there might be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: @SagebrushGardener take a look of the update please, let me know if the idea is clear

Comment: @ernest_k I am not sure what the point was of creating two different instances of the class in the first place. There does not seem to be any other purpose for it. I can pass an additional parameter to let delete() know the state of the calling method, but I thought maybe the different instance names would somehow be detectable from within delete().